# Is Display Tag compatible with IE 9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, displaytag

I know this is not the relevant programming question but I couldn't find any resource to know if IE 9 or even 8 supports Display Tag Library. Documentation doesn't say anything about the browser support.

Please share if anyone has ever experienced any difficulty while using Display Tag with IE 8,9 or 10. It works with 11 I know that :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Display tag is compatible up to IE5 because I could only go that much far using IE's developer console where I could change the browser version from default in my case edge to 5.